# SQL Select Distinct on Two Different Columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table looks like this:

```
ID    from    to
1      X      Y
2      Y      X
3      Z      X
4      R      L
```

Please note the two first rows:

```
1      X         Y
2      Y         X
```

What I want is to prevent the same value on reversed column/different column, or `from != to` and I want the SQL return:

```
ID    from    to
1      X      Y
3      Z      X
4      R      L
```

Can SQL do this?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: @David PostgreSQL

Comment: "want is to prevent the reversed value" do you want to prevent it as a constraint (so it cannt be entered) or just suppress the output of the reversed values in a select statement, it's not clear what you really want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DISTINCT` clause is not the right tool for this job, but you can easily eliminate the "duplicate" rows yourself like this:

```
select *
from Table1 AS T1
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from  Table1 AS T2
  where T1.from = T2.to
  and   T1.to = t2.from
  and   T1.id > T2.id 
  )
```

Here is a working sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/89047/1

Answer (score 2):

I combined the columns and sorted them together.
Then I remove the duplicate using group by. Se demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/72d28/17

```
Select tbl.* 
from tbl
Join 
(Select min(id) as id
From (Select id,
Case when fromcol > tocol then fromcol || tocol
else tocol || fromcol  end as combined
From tbl) s
Group by combined) t
On tbl.id = t.id;


   Result:
    id  fromcol tocol
   1    x   y
   3    z   x
   4    r   l
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by a normalized combination of `from` and `to`:

```
select min(id) as id, 
       least("from", "to") as "from",
       greatest("from", "to") as "to"
from the_table
group by least("from", "to"), greatest("from", "to")
order by 1;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/ZTRR72072

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `least()` and `greatest()` function to find smallest and largest value from both column

```
select * from table t
where id in (
       select min(id) from table 
       group by least(from, to), greatest(from, to)
)
```